# How can I scan the result of a Golang SQL query built with Jet into a user-defined slice of structs?

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, go

Is there any way I could scan result of SQL query built with Golang [Jet SQL builder](https://github.com/go-jet/jet) into a slice of structs defined by user (not generated models of Jet)?

This operation is [straightforward](https://github.com/go-jet/jet/wiki/Statements) in case querying into a struct generated by this SQL builder but unobvious for custom structs.

I had tried to search across documentation but did not find anything related. I presume I can obtain query and args variables using Sql() method of the library but I wonder if there is a shorter way.

Comment: does [this](https://github.com/go-jet/jet/wiki/Query-Result-Mapping-(QRM)#custom-model-types) answer your question?